# Using locate-template & shortcodes doesn't appear to work

Tags: functions, templates, shortcode

For organisation, I'm trying to split up the functions.php file into separate files. In particular the functions for shortcodes in a separate file, with the shortcodes being defined in functions.php. Here's the code in the functions.php:-

```
locate_template( array( 'inc/shortcode-functions.php' ), true, true ); 
add_shortcode( 'abc-row', 'echo_abc_row' );
add_shortcode( 'abc-span', 'echo_abc_span' );
```

I have taken the code out of inc/shortcode-functions.php into the functions.php, so does appear to work, and no error is coming up in debug mode, so I'm a bit stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `locate_template()` function is intended to be used to locate/include *template* files, not *functional* files.

Just use `include()` and/or `require()` to include functional files in `functions.php`.

Answer (score 0):

***If and only if*** you are looking for a way to make your `shortcode-functions.php` file overrideable by child themes I'd suggest [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part), like this:

```
get_template_part('inc/shortcode-functions');
```

Notice that there is no `.php` at the end. That will load your file, whereas [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) will fail. (I just tested it.) The difference between the two is that [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) does a little bit more work constructing file paths.

If you aren't trying to make it overrideable by a child theme, just use `include`.