# Load .txt file for login_message in wp-login.php

Tags: functions, wp-login-form

How do I load the contents of a text file - or any other file, like .php - and use the test for the `login_message` hook that prints a message above the `#login` box in wp-login.php?

*(BTW, this is in a child theme, if it makes a difference.)*

```
function custom_login_message() {

$message = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')."/tos.txt";
return $message;
}
add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');
```

Right now, the function above prints out the URL of the file, not the text in the file, i.e.:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`locate_template()`](http://queryposts.com/function/locate_template/) if you want to use a file from your theme. `include()` or `require()` works too.

Sample code, tested:

```
add_filter( 'login_message', 'wpse_73619_include_login_message' );

function wpse_73619_include_login_message()
{
    print '<pre>';
    locate_template( 'style.css', TRUE );
    print '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Works great and is the simplest way to pull that file in; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your function just constructs the URL. You'd need to [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file to get at its contents. You may be able to do this with [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part). I am not sure about the hook context. However, your file would need to generate a PHP variable or it will echo immediately rather than return.

If you are using a text file, you could look into one of PHP's file functions, like [`get_file_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for more complicated manipulation of the file contents before your echo/return it. Or use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

Comment: Thanks, that should work. `get_template_part` actually uses  `locate_template()`, so toscho's idea works more directly.

Comment: `locate_template` will fail in places that `get_template_part` does not. If you look at the source for them both you will see that `get_template_part` does more work to find the file. [This thread is an example.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73210/using-locate-template-shortcodes-doesnt-appear-to-work/73232#73232)

Comment: You're right, good point. This is for use in a child theme. But I can see the difference now.